# LinearLayout translucent (but not transparent)

Tags: android, layout

I would like a LinearLayout translucent (I don't mean transparent).
I want to emulate a Dialog in my Activity. So I tried this:

In Manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

In Activity onCreate:

```
LinearLayout MyLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MyLayout);  
MyLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); 
MyLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
```

But it doesn't work because I don't see the Home Desktop at all. Any idea?

I also tried this in xml but it din't work either:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/MyLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#22FFFFFF"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an hexadecimal color code, wich consists of two digits for alpha and six for the color itself, like this:

```
android:background="#22FFFFFF"
```

It'll make it semi-transparent.

Comment: Sorry but it dindn't work for me. Besides I had to change "22FFFFFF" to "#22FFFFFF".

Comment: @delive if you're planning to make an entire activity semi-transparent, you need to make sure that the Activity uses a transparent theme.